# App-generated requests to user’s friends

Tags: facebook, request

The Facebook documentation says that I can use app-generated requests to communicate with users who have installed my app. Is it also possible to send app-generated requests to that user's friends who haven’t installed my app yet?

I think I have seen some such requests by games like Farmville etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to send an app to user request to a user's friends who haven't installed the app - see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/requests/#app_to_user for more details about app to user requests.

What you can do, is ask a user to invite their friends to use your app using a user to user request with the request dialog https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/. You could preselect only friends who haven't installed.